# Getting size of request in IActionFilter OnActionExecuting()

Tags: c#, request, asp.net-core-2.1

Project setup: Asp .NET core 2.1, Web Api on Docker environment.

I want to get size of the GET requests with query parameters on our API for logging purpose.
I have an action filter implementing IActionFilter in the project. OnActionExecuting() is the method where I interpret the request for the purpose.

But I am always getting null in context.HttpContext.Request.ContentLength property. Also, read the body by stream reader in a text variable which is is also empty. 
Is this a valid place to check this or else am I referring to different property of the ActionExecutingContext ?

```
public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
{

string requestSize = "";

//Try 1:
requestSize = Convert.ToString(context.HttpContext.Request.ContentLength);

//Try 2:
//Since the Try 1 is null, following doesn't really matter. But still tried.
using (var bodyReader = new StreamReader(context.HttpContext.Request.Body))
{
     var bodyAsText = bodyReader.ReadToEnd();
     if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(bodyAsText) == false)
     {
     requestSize = bodyAsText.Length;
     }
}

// Console.WriteLine(requestSize );

}
```

Expecting some bytes number for the request size, but getting null.

Comment: GET requests do not have a BODY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this a valid place to check this

**NO**

GET requests do not have a BODY.

`ContentLength` being null and empty body stream are expected behavior for GET requests.

If you want access to query strings then you need to check the request and extract the query string

```
context.HttpContext.Request.QueryString
```

Comment: Thanks @Nkosi. It helped. Now, in OnActionExecuted(), I have to get size of the response. Here also, I get null in context.HttpContext.Response.ContentLength, while the response does have fair amount of data. I found that in context.Result, can I get the bytes of the result ?

Comment: @Arjun_TECH The response should have the data in it, provided there is actual content to return. Have you tried checking the response body as well?

Comment: yes as I said, the response does have the data which I can see in the context.Result property. More specifically : ((Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ObjectResult)context.Result).Value. And by Body if you mean context.HttpContext.Response.Body, there is nothing in it.

Comment: The that means the action result has not been executed as yet so it has not had time to populate the response body.